# LWJGL 2 Code Not Compatible with LWJGL 3 Code?

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick2d

I'm very new to using external Java libraries, and I'm starting with Slick2D which is built upon LWJGL. I wrote a simple StateBasedGame that just prints three options on a screen. It gives me an error though about some (jar?) file not being present (see below for reference).

This reminds me of the fact that most of the tutorials I come across were made one or two years ago when LWJGL 3 hadn't come out or wasn't stable yet. This means that they were all using LWJGL 2. The problem is, that a lot of the code that I try using LWJGL 3 doesn't work with the code that was originally written in LWJGL 2. Why is this? Would it be a good idea to switch back to LWJGL 2 if I wanted to learn SLick2D? Please help because simple programs that I write don't even compile.

Here's my code that doesn't work (at least in LWJGL 3):

```
import org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame;

public class Game extends StateBasedGame {

    Menu menu;

    public Game(String title) {
        super(title);
        menu = new Menu(0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            AppGameContainer agc = new AppGameContainer(new Game("Text Based"));
            agc.setDisplayMode(600, 600, false);
            agc.start();
        } catch (SlickException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void initStatesList(GameContainer container) throws SlickException {
        System.out.println("InitStates");
        addState(new Menu(0));
        getState(menu.getID()).init(container, this);
        enterState(menu.getID());
    }
}


import org.newdawn.slick.Color;
import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.BasicGameState;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame;

public class Menu extends BasicGameState {

    private int ID;
    private int menu;

    public Menu(int id) {
        this.ID = id;
    }

    @Override
    public void init(GameContainer container, StateBasedGame sbg) throws SlickException {
    }

    @Override
    public void render(GameContainer container, StateBasedGame game, Graphics g) throws SlickException {
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.drawString("Higher or Lower", 50, 10);

        g.drawString("1. Play Game", 50, 100);
        g.drawString("2. High Scores", 50, 120);
        g.drawString("3. Quit", 50, 140);

    }

    @Override
    public void update(GameContainer arg0, StateBasedGame arg1, int arg2) throws SlickException {

    }

    @Override
    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }

}
```

Here is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl64 in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:72)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.doLoadLibrary(Sys.java:66)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.loadLibrary(Sys.java:87)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:117)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:135)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer$1.run(AppGameContainer.java:39)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.<clinit>(AppGameContainer.java:36)
    at Game.main(Game.java:17)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LWJGL 3 is a complete rewrite of the library, so naturally most code from LWJGL 2 won't work with it. Slick2D still uses LWJGL 2 under the hood, which makes it incompatible with LWJGL 3.

The error you are getting is there because Slick2D calls the LWJGL 2 display functionality, which tries to load the `lwjgl64.dll` native file. However, in LWJGL 3 the native libraries have been renamed (`lwjgl32` and `lwjgl` instead of `lwjgl` and `lwjgl64`), so it can't find it. Even if it did, loading dlls and jars of both versions at the same time (LWJGL 2 by Slick2D and LWJGL 3 by your code) most likely won't work well.

If you want to use Slick2D you have to use LWJGL 2. However, LWJGL 3 is already quite stable and comes with some helper libraries you can use to do common tasks like loading image files, so I advise you to at least take a look at it (it offers some nice features like multi-window support).

Comment: Okay, thanks! This cleared up a lot of problems for me because I couldn't find any lwjgl64.dll file while I could find a lwjgl32.dll file. I'm glad you told me this now because it all made no sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

you're missing lwjgl64 from your library path.  I.E. your missing the native parts.  Either you didn't put it in your java.library or it's missing from the classpath and your working dir.  I believe it's a .dll for windows and a .so for linux so make sure you are including lwjgl correctly for your project and you should be fine however, take a read here: [LWJGL3 Migration Guide](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3-wiki/wiki/2.6.6-LWJGL3-migration)

Comment: I can't find any file called lwjgl64 though. The only thing that I've found online so far is to set my "Native Library Location" to a "windows" folder that was in the file that I downloaded. That didn't work though...